# Program hangs after opening file with open and fdopen

Tags: c

I'm using `open()` with `O_RDWR` and then using the descriptor in `fdopen()` with `"r+"`. I check that the file exists first with `access()`, and check for `open()` returning -1 then check that the `FILE *fp` set from `fdopen()` isn't `NULL`.

Now whenever I use any function such as `fgets()` or `fgetc()` with `fp` the program hangs in my terminal. I get no compiler warnings. Any ideas?

[image]

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char buffer[512];
    int file_descriptor;
    FILE *file;

    if (argc != 2) {
        puts("ERROR: Missing argument");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (access(argv[1], F_OK) == -1) { // Check if file exists
        puts("ERROR: File does not exist");
        exit(0);
    } else if (file_descriptor = open(argv[1], O_RDWR) == -1) { // Check for open() failure
        puts("ERROR: Unable to open file using open()");
        exit(0);
    }

    file = fdopen(file_descriptor, "r+"); // Use descriptor

    if (file == NULL) {
        puts("ERROR: Unable to open file using fdopen()");
        fclose(file);
        exit(0);
    }

    // fscanf(file, "%c", stdout); // Hangs
    // fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), file); // Hangs
    printf("%c", fgetc(file)); // Hangs

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could use `fopen` instead of `open` + `fdopen`. Also `clang` gave me a bunch of warnings about how you're using `open`.

Comment: @Schwern School assignment requirement. Haven't got far into it though thanks to me messing up operator precedence!

Comment: Also, you're not running with warnings, they have to be turned on: `cc -Wall`. If your prof didn't tell you this, shame on them. And I'd recommend using `-std=c99`, the C99 standard, and avoid getting too used to GNU extensions. And my final piece of advice is to learn [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) now.

Comment: @Insane as you can imagine, there are *hundreds* of duplicates of this on this site, but each of them is under such a wide array of usages and divergent titles, it's difficult to find such duplicates by searching, as you may have found out.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The expression

```
file_descriptor = open(argv[1], O_RDWR) == -1
```

does not work as you expect it to, because the equality operator `==` have higher [*precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) than the assignment operator. That means the expression is more like

```
file_descriptor = (open(argv[1], O_RDWR) == -1)
```

which means your `file_descriptor` will be either `0` or `1` depending on how the comparison went.

You need to use parentheses for the assignment:

```
(file_descriptor = open(argv[1], O_RDWR)) == -1
```

Comment: For this reason it's best to do the open on one line and the check on another.

Comment: @Schwern This is what I get for trying to be fancy

Comment: @Insane just always use parantheses

Answer (score 6):

To add to the other answer. It's "hanging" because the bug causes it actually to read standard input (file descriptor 0). Try typing something and it will read it.

Comment: This is really good to know too.

Comment: Please consider this answer as a comment because it is not a solution or enhancement to the already posted answer.